# How to connect PSU to these PCB pads

Tags: pcb-design, connector

I have the Maxim Integrated evaluation kit for one of their chips ([MAX14830EVKIT](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14830EVKIT.pdf)), and would like to understand what the intended way is to connect the two PSUs (24V and 3.3V, both 100mA) to this PCB.

The PCB has two pairs of small pads, each with two small holes:

[image: 24V pads]
[image: 3.3V pads]

- I could solder wires onto the PCB, but that does not seem appropriate for a "fully assembled and tested" board.
- I got some test probe grabbers, but they don't go into the holes.
- The pads and holes seem too small to screw some binding post into.

What is the right tool to use here?

Comment: What is the part number of the eval board?

Comment: Updated in the post

Comment: You are indeed meant to solder your connector pigtail wires to those pads. If you prefer to use clip leads, standard 0.025" square pin headers will fit. And in this context fully assembled and tested refers to the EVKIT board itself, we can't know what connector you will use, if any. We use a custom test fixture with spring-loaded pogo pins to contact those pads from below. This approach lets you eliminate contact resistance or use whichever connector you want. (I am one of the EV kit designers at Maxim, though I don't recognize the board in the photo.)

Comment: @MarkU You should add this as an answer. There is no more authoritative source than the designers themselves!

Comment: @MarkU. You have essentially answered the question, so you should post it as an answer-not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed meant to solder your connector pigtail wires to those pads. If you prefer to use clip leads, standard 0.025" square pin headers will fit. And in this context fully assembled and tested refers to the Evaluation Kit board itself, we can't know what connector you will use, if any. We use a custom test fixture with spring-loaded "pogo pins" to contact those pads from below. This approach lets you eliminate contact resistance or use whichever connector you want. (I am one of the EV kit designers at Maxim Integrated... although I'm not the designer of the MAX14830EVKIT, I have designed many similar EV kits.)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @MarkU - I think I'll solder on some header pins. As a design suggestion, a test point or something that is friendly to an alligator clip (perhaps in addition to the pads) would have been welcome, making a solderless breadboarding setup a bit simpler and more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably designed for test points [like this example](http://towerfast.com/press/post/new-products-from-keystone-include-color-coded-pcb-mount-test-points). These are popular and available from many different manufacturers.

Or you can make a half loop with bare wire and solder each end to a hole.

Comment: Those do look like they could work, and would have been nice to have on the board already.

Answer (score 0):

1. Solder wires directly to the oblong pads.
2. Solder male "header pins" into the holes (assuming 0.1 inch / 2.54mm spacing) Then you could use 2-pin female mating connectors for connecting and disconnecting the power wires.

Clearly each of these options (and perhaps others) have their advantages and disadvantages. Since only you know all the conditions you are working with, only you can decide which method makes the most sense.